# Formatting a number in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting, cultureinfo

I want to seperate a number with commas. I have tried many ways to do it. But didn't work.

Its already converted to a string and now i want to format the "tot".

```
GetData getData = new GetData();
string tot = Convert.ToString(getData.Total_Extra(month));
string totVal = (tot).ToString("N",new CultureInfo("en-US"));
LB2.Text = tot.ToString();
```

Comment: What are your actual and expected outputs?

Comment: I would look into https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I expect the value in the label to be shown like this 19,950,000.00

Comment: And how is it currently displaying it?

Comment: It shows like this 19950000.00. but with the above code it creates an error. I dont prefer to do it as in above code. But i want some how to format the string value as i need.

Comment: what is the value of the variable `tot` - we can't simulate your call to `GetData()`

Comment: Sum of few numbers are taken as the value of tot

Comment: You should show the code that you tried and what "didn't work" entails

Comment: In your latest edit, shouldn't it be `LB2.Text = totVal;` ?

Comment: Just try 1 thing Replace your last line : `LB2.Text = tot.ToString();` with this 
`LB2.Text = tot.ToString("n2");` Hope it works for you :)

Comment: I divided Matt's answer into two steps and now its working well. Thank you both Sunil and Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `tot` string to a numeric value and then use `string.Format` to get the desired format:

```
string tot = "19950000";
string output = string.Format("{0:n2}", Convert.ToInt32(tot));
Debug.WriteLine(output); //19,950,000.00 on my machine
```

or alternatively:

```
string output2 = Convert.ToInt32(tot).ToString("n2");
```

These are both **culture specific**, so might display differently on different users machines (Indian culture will display `1,99,50,000.00` for example).

If you want to *force* the three digit comma grouping then you can specify a culture to use:

```
string output2 = Convert.ToInt32(tot).ToString("n2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
//19,950,000.00 on any machine
```

It sounds like your `tot` may not be a numeric value, so you should check this before trying to format it:

```
string tot = "19950000";
int totInt;
if (Int32.TryParse(tot, out totInt))
{
    string output = totInt.ToString("n2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
    MessageBox.Show(output);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("tot could not be parsed to an Int32");
}
```

Comment: I tried it too But creates an exception. I have upload the current code and please take a look.

Comment: GetData getData = new GetData();
            string tot = Convert.ToString(getData.Total_Extra(month));
            string totVal = string.Format("0:n2", Convert.ToInt32(tot)); 
            LB2.Text = totVal.ToString();

Comment: There you have tried to a float but i want to format a string value

Comment: Matt Wilko - I have tried with and without curly braces. I get exception saying wrong input type

Comment: @MattWilko : Mate that is the code you have put in your answer, I just want to say I have tried your code and that is working fine. The screenshot for OP  :)

Comment: Matt Wilko - I split your answer into two steps and now it's working. Thank you for the help